# mat checkbox inside scrollable div causing issue

Tags: checkbox, scroll, angular-material

I have mat checkboxes inside a scrollable div. When scrolling the div the check boxes are not rendering properly. If the focus is removed from the div the checkboxes are appearing fine.

Here is the sample of the problem:
[mat-checkbox issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haYri.gif)

Comment: Angular Versions:
"@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "~10.2.1",

This problem is happening in Chrome only, Tried on Edge its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to the problem but it is one of the most bizarre solution I ever did:

1. Overridden the margin right property of mat-checkbox-inner-container

   :host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
   margin-right: 0px !important;
   }

This leaves no space between the checkbox and label

Weirdly if the label and checkbox are touched the problem goes away, if there is even 1 pixel gap between checkbox and label the issue occurs

2. added "&nbsp" to generate the gap between checkbox and label:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filterGroup.filters;" >
         <div class="filter">
            <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "filter.isSelected"
                          (change)="onChanges(filter.id, i)">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{filter.text}}
             </mat-checkbox>
         </div>
</ng-container>
```